# MySQL Event If Statement END IF Error

Tags: mysql

Trying to create a MySQL event that resets a `soldout` status (indicated as `1`).

The logic I'm trying to create is a simple IF statement.

If `soldout` = `1` AND `Quantity` > `0` in the same row

UPDATE `soldout` to `0`

Here is my event

```
CREATE EVENT soldoutreset
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
DO
IF db.Inventory.soldout = 1
AND db.Inventory.Quantity > 0 THEN
UPDATE db.Inventory SET soldout = 0
WHERE soldout = 1 AND Quantity > 1
END IF;
```

This is resulting in an error, `'END IF' at line 9`

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 9
```

Can anyone tell why this is not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work, you are missing a part of the syntax:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE EVENT soldoutreset
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
    DO
    BEGIN
        IF db.Inventory.soldout = 1 AND db.Inventory.Quantity > 0 THEN
            UPDATE db.Inventory SET soldout = 0
            WHERE soldout = 1 AND Quantity > 1;
        END IF;
    END |

DELIMITER ;
```

**Update:**

If the event is not running as expected, it might be because the event scheduler is off. It can be enabled with:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Comment: I am still getting the same (or similar error) `...to use near 'END IF;
    END' at line 8`

Comment: In my initial answer I missed `BEGIN ` dans I updated the answer since. Try again with the current version please

Comment: I believe I had the `BEGIN` inititally, I don't see an edit.  Still, I try and still getting the `END IF; END` error.

Comment: @BrianBruman I was missing the `;` at the end of the update query, please try again.

Comment: Yes it processed correctly. Thank you for the help with the missing syntax. Still looking into why it is not working properly, I'm trying different things.  After 5 minutes my test row with a `Quantity` of `17` and a `soldout` of `1` still shows `1` after 5 minutes which is not my intended `0`

Comment: try: SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

Comment: Haha.  How did you know.  Okay, I turned it ON.  This is my first MySQL Event I've tried to create by the way :)  I will accept in a min

Comment: Also, the `IF...` and `END IF;` line sounds strange to me, you could try removing them if it does not work.

Comment: Doy, I guess I don't even need an IF statement :P  It worked with just `UPDATE db.inventory SET soldout = 0
            WHERE soldout = 1 AND Quantity > 1`.  Seems so easy now. Thank you for the help!